# Ionic 2 - Como eu volto para a pagina inicial de uma determinada tab

Tags: ionic, ionic2, angular

Meu APP trabalha com `tabs`, dentro dessas `tabs` eu tenho botões que abrem outras paginas usando o `push`, quando eu clico na `tab 2`, e clico em um botão, ele abre a pagina normal, ai eu clico na `tab 1`, e depois clico de novo na `tab 2`, só que ao invés dele mostrar a pagina inicial da `tab 2`, ele já vem aberto com a pagina que eu tinha clicado antes.

Como faço para que toda vez q ele clicar em uma aba, ele mostre exatamente a pagina inicial daquela `tab`, e não traga aberta a pagina que eu havia visitado? Tentei usar o `this.tabRef.select(0);` dentro do `tab.ts`, mas ele clica duas vezes no primeiro clique de cada `tab`, o que provoca um piscar na tela a deixando em branco por alguns segundos por chamar duas vezes a mesma..

Tentei o `this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);`, mas ele tira as `tabs` da tela, pois assume HomePage como pagina inicial.

**RESOLVIDO**
Só colocar nas paginas internas isso
`ionViewDidLeave(){
   this.navController.setRoot(/*sua pagina inicia da tab*/);
}`

Comment: Pode postar seu trecho de código? Fica mais fácil para a comunidade te ajudar.

Comment: Isso é algo dá própria tab do ionic 2... só queria saber uma forma dele não deixar aberto e tirar da pilha a pagina anterior, ou ao clicar na tab, ele sempre trazer a pagina setada no root da `TabsPage`... tentei usar o `pop` dentro da `ionViewWillLeave()`, mas ai ele aparece um warning **You can't remove all the pages in the navigation stack. nav.pop() is probably called too many times**